# multi UIView subclass create in loop

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i create a UIView subclass that name is "GameCard"

and i also create xib file. and added one UIView.

so i want add each GameCard class to ivew in loopping

so I wrote this codes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSArray *nibViews =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"GameCard" owner:self options:nil];
    GameCard *aGameCard = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
    for (int i = 0; i < [gameWordData1 count]; i++) {
        int x = i / 3;
        int y = i % 3;
        GameCard *bGameCard = [aGameCard copy];
        bGameCard.frame = CGRectMake((10 + y * 100), (x * 70), 100, 70);
        [self.view addSubview:bGameCard];
    }
}
```

so I saw just one GameCard class in view

so I try this code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
for (int i = 0; i < [gameWordData1 count]; i++) {
    int x = i / 3;
    int y = i % 3;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake((10 + y * 100), (x * 70), 100, 70);
    GameCard *aGameCard = [[GameCard alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [self.view addSubview:aGameCard];
    NSLog(@"%i", [[self.view subviews] count]);
}
}
```

I saw anythins in view. but it seems GameCard class is created.

what's wrong my code.

sorry about my english :)

Comment: Are your x and y args reversed in the line: CGRect rect = CGRectMake((10 + y * 100), (x * 70), 100, 70);

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest loading the nib file for each view. To make speed up the process, you can use UINib instead of NSBundle to load the data.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"GameCard" bundle:nil];
    for(int i = 0; i < [gameWordData1 count]; i++) {
        int x = i / 3;
        int y = i % 3;
        NSArray *nibViews = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];
        GameCard *aGameCard = [nibViews objectAtIndex:0];
        aGameCard.frame = CGRectMake((10+y*100),(x*70),100,70);
        [self.view addSubview:aGameCard];
    }
}
```

PS: As @jamihash noted in the comments, you may have accidentally switched x and y in CGRectMake. I used it the way you had it in your code, but check it before you use it.

Comment: So, [nib instantiateWithOwner:self ... ] self is the view, right ? If I'm writing the code from the parent ViewController, I should specify [nib instantiateWithOwner:myCustomView ...] right ?

Comment: `self` should be replaced with whatever object is specified as the owner of the NIB. In the question, self was used to load the nib, so I also used it, but you should use whatever object is supposed to be the owner.